# Image not Refreshing from http url in image control in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app with following code

```
    url = "http://mywebsite/image.jpg";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    image1.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

The problem is that the image is not refreshing after loading again and again its always the same.
How can i refresh it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the default behavior of an Image control in Windows Phone "Mango" is to cache the image.

If you add an image like this:

```xml
<Image Source="http://domain/image.png" />
```

It will have a default behavior like this:

```xml
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage CreateOptions="DelayCreation" UriSource="http://domain/image.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

As you can see here, this is controlled with the [BitmapImage.CreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property.

In your case, you should just change the default behavior to something like this:

```xml
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage CreateOptions="DelayCreation,IgnoreImageCache" UriSource="http://domain/image.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Should work fine... I suggest you use Fiddler to check the communication is being done correctly, and post a sample so we can help you better